# Node.js and Express version migration did not work

Tags: node.js, express

I am not able to connect to the below NODE.JS app. Maybe, I did anything wrong with changing an old code to the latest express and node.js versions?

app.js

```
global.settings = {
    port:       8003,
    dbPort:     27017,
    dbHost:     'localhost',
    dbName:     "admin-linux",
    root_path:  __dirname
}
var DB = require('./app/server/modules/db-manager');

DB.init(function(){
    var express = require('express')
      , http = require('http');

    var app = express(); 
    var server = http.createServer(app);

    require('./app/setup')(app, express);
    require('./app/server/router')(app);

    app.listen(global.settings.port, function(){
        console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", global.settings.port, app.settings.env);
    });
});
```

setup.js

```
var DB = require('./server/modules/db-manager');

module.exports = function(app, exp) {
    app.get(function(){
        app.set('views', global.settings.root_path + '/app/server/views');
        app.set('view engine', 'jade');
        app.set('view options', { doctype : 'html', pretty : true });
        app.use(exp.bodyParser());
        app.use(exp.cookieParser());
        app.use(exp.session({ secret: 'super-duper-secret-secret' }));
        app.use(exp.methodOverride());
        app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: global.settings.root_path + '/app/public' }));
        app.use(exp.static(global.settings.root_path + '/app/common'));
        app.use(exp.static(global.settings.root_path + '/app/public'));
        app.use(exp.static(global.settings.root_path + '/customize'));
        app.use(DB.i18n.init);
    });
};
```

Comment: what error do you meet? seems unclear what is your issue?

Comment: No error in terminal, but `localhost:8003` in browser returned `Unable to connect`

Comment: Generally speaking, `app.get(path, callback`, the first parameter is `path`, and handling request and response in the callback function. Also those `app.use` and `app.set` are set NOT in this way.... Do your codes run correctly before?

Comment: The orginal code `https://github.com/gianlucadelgobbo/mongo-invoices` was running, but I wanted to use the latest versions of node.js, express, mongo,.... While changing the code to satisfy the changes in the new versions i somehow broke the code and I do not how to fix it.